# How can I apply a timeout to an Ant task?

Tags: ant, timeout

Without writing a custom Ant task, is there a way to use a timeout on a regular ant target?

To give some background info: we are using the 'delete' task to remove the contents of a given directory.
Sometimes this directory is massive, with lots of generated folders and files.
We wanted to have that task timeout after, say, 5 minutes.

Answer (score 11):

You might use the [parallel](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) task, which has a timeout, with a parallel degree of one:

```
<target name="timed_del">
    <parallel threadCount="1" timeout="300000">
        <sequential>
            ... your tasks here ...
        </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

Comment: Yea this works. I've used parallel before but I did not even think to use it here ... not sure why. But thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: would this solve the infinite timeout on ftp task? ie if an ftp task is stuck in a timeout..

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [limit](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/limit_task.html) task.

```
<target name="my-target">
  <limit seconds="2" failonerror="true">
    <sshexec ... />
  </limit>
</target>
```