# Jenkins .without stopped jboss application to set timeout in build.xml using ant

Tags: ant, jenkins, jboss, build.xml

I am Using Jenkin (build.xml) using ant.How to set the timing out in build.xml or after complete application deployed then that task was timeout without the application stop/kill?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463385/how-can-i-apply-a-timeout-to-an-ant-task

Comment: No this is not my question.My question is Don't kill any application after deployed only jumped out/time out that task not killed are stopped.So please answer this,am waiting for your valuable reply.